# system policy: java(4297) deny(1) file-write-mode on mac os

Tags: macos, install4j, osquery

In my Project I am trying to install one install4j build there osquery.app also gets installed.

OS:- Mac os Ventura

In fresh install osquery.app gets installed properly do not get any error in my folder .But when I try upgrade scenario osquery.app in console gives this error

> system policy: java(4297) deny(1) file-write-mode /Library/Application Support/test/osquery.app

Tried SIP disable it works there.But now I want it to work in SIP enable.
Can anyone help? I am not understanding is it related to install4j or osquery.app or java

Answer (score 0):

"osquery" usually refers to https://osquery.io/ which is not a java program. This is quite unclear.

Furthermore, disabling SIP is not recommended on macOS

Comment: Thanks for response but I have already mentioned that I am installing osquery using install4j. install4j uses the java. Yes I am aware of SIP disable is not recommended that is why I am asking for solution with SIP enable.

Comment: What is install4j's osquery?

Comment: install4j is tool https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/main/introduction.html
using which I am creating installer. I have made provision that it will install osquery.app. It installs osquery.app. but at the time of upgrade it is giving above error

Comment: Ah. So you're using install4j to create an installer than _additionally_ bundles in oquery. But you're running into the original error?

Do you need to install to `/Library/Application Support`? Maybe it's recommended, but I think you'd do better installing it as part of your app bundle